# Rails not working on Mac in new terminal window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal, rvm

I have been using RVM (Rails 2.0.0) for a project in the terminal doing commands etc. and have noticed that when I opened a new terminal page the rails command didn't work it just shot back the error:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails
```

But I had it installed and have even built half an app using it so far... what happened all of a sudden and how do I fix it to keep going with my project.

Comment: try1=> cmd:`rvm reload`, try2=> `close and reopen terminal`

Comment: @Nithin I tried that and that worked to get rails working on my mac but I still have the issue when I cd into the root of my project the follow error appears: RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /sample_app/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

$ rails s
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on with the Rails tutorial.  It looks like rvm is using the gemset defined in the Gemfile to override the default gemset.  You should see this if you execute:

```
rvm gemset list_all
```

What I saw was this:

```
   (default)
   global
=> railstutorial_rails_4_0
```

So rails is fully installed in rvm's default gemset, but not in the new one ("railstutorial_rails_4_0" in this case).  I solved this with the following commands:

```
bundle install --without production
bundle update
bundle install
```

This solution appears to have persisted across terminal sessions.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so I got it to work by simple removing the code in the Gemfile that states the version of Ruby the app is to use and then it worked fine. Must of been some conflict with RVM installed on my machine and the Gemfile.